# Mysql show average of selected options

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has a unique id for each question:

| Question_Id | Selected_Option |
| --- | --- |
| 65 | Option A |
| 101 | Option B |
| 65 | Option C |

How I should return the average selection for each question?
for example for question 65 I want to show that 50 % is Option A and 50 % is Option C
as like that for question 101 it return that 100% is Option B

Comment: Please include the exact output you want here.

Comment: I want the output like I put the question id and the question is attempted by only 2 peoples and 1 person selected the Option A and the 2nd person selected Option C then the result should be display that 50% is Option A and 50% is Option C same in the case in example in table which I have mentioned so the 65 no question is attempted by 2 peoples so it should return that Option A is selected by 50% and Option C is selected by 50%

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into the question, rather than leaving them as [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: I started to answer but I was filling in too many gaps. Rather than a paragraph about your goal, can you show in table form what you want that information to look like? Is there a row for each question and a column for each option? Do questions all have the same number of options? Are they named `Option A` etc or is that a placeholder for the text of the answer? Think carefully about what you want the final result to look like, and share that with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct question_id,
concat(selected_option,' has a select percentage of ',
    (select  truncate(count(case selected_option when q.selected_option then 1 end) /count(selected_option)*100,0) 
     from questions
     where question_id=q.question_id
     group by question_id), -- this correlated query calculates the percentage for the main query's selected_option of its associated question_id
     '%'
) as percentage
from questions q
;

-- result set:
65, Option A has a select percentage of 50%
101, Option B has a select percentage of 100%
65, Option C has a select percentage of 50%

-- let's make it more interesting:
insert into questions values(65,'Option C'),(65,'Option D');

-- execute the query again and the result set will be:
65, Option A has a select percentage of 25%
101, Option B has a select percentage of 100%
65, Option C has a select percentage of 50%
65, Option D has a select percentage of 25%
```